# while using ng2-daterangepicker find build issue, not importing ng2-daterangepicker from node_modules instead looking on project root

Tags: angular5

I am using ng2-daterangepicker but while importing import { Daterangepicker } from 'ng2-daterangepicker'; getting error while building as No such file or directory found on project root.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your system.js file.

```
map: {
    // angular bundles

    // add ng2-daterangepicker bundles
    'ng2-daterangepicker': 'npm:ng2-daterangepicker',
    'jquery': 'npm:jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    'moment': 'npm:moment',
    'bootstrap-daterangepicker': 'npm:bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js'
},
packages: {
    // other packages already defined

    // ng2-daterangepicker packages
    moment: {
        main: 'moment',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'ng2-daterangepicker': {
        main: 'index',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
     }
}
```

Check your app.module as well.

```
import { Daterangepicker } from 'ng2-daterangepicker';

@NgModule({
    imports: [Daterangepicker]
})
```

Comment: yes I updated systemjs.config.js file and also imported in my module but it is looking for ng2-daterangepicker at project lavel like my project is gcu-sis.sisweb and I am getting below error : ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IdeaProjects\GCU_Project\GCU_Code_Base\sprint94\gcu-sis.sisweb\ng2-daterangepicker'?[39m

Comment: I have one main module and one sub module, do I need to import Daterangepicker in both or only in sub module is file

Comment: In the submodule only.

Comment: could you please share if you have working app using ng2-daterangepicker @Nimish goel